# O que é código dinâmico e código estático?

Tags: terminologia

Recentemente em uma conversa com amigos surgiu o termo **código dinâmico** e **código estático**. Com isso veio uma certa discussão. Uns disseram que código dinâmico está relacionado com [scaffolding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_(programming)), outros com [análise de código](http://www.embedded.com/design/safety-and-security/4419779/Static-vs--dynamic-analysis-for-secure-code-development--Part-1). Outros dizem que é o simples fato do sistema gerar o código para você.

Mas na verdade, o que é **código dinâmico** e **código estático**?
Algumas ou todas essas descrições estão corretas?

Comment: Depende do contexto. Na forma atual, acho difícil dar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: @bigown Esses termos não tem um "significado" padrão, ou global, por assim dizer?

Comment: Desconheço. E parece que cada um dos dois estão sendo usados "nessa conversa" pra coisas tão distintas que já mostra isto. Parece que não estão sendo usados uma em oposição ao outro.A busca óbvia no Google mostra que isto tem a ver com análise de código, nos dois casos, mas isto é uma falha do Google. A palavra "análise" faz toda diferença no contexto.

Comment: @bigown Então essas definições não estão erradas? Claro, dependendo do contexto.

Comment: Dependendo do contexto qualquer coisa está certa :) Pra mim código estático é aquele que é todo gerado em tempo de desenvolvimento e código dinâmico é aquele que é gerado em tempo de execução. Por geração, pode entender como adaptação também.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown. Já me ajudou. Vou deixar a pergunta aperta para ver se mais alguém tem alguma opinião. Mas se quiser, pode votar para fechar, realmente concordo com você que está um pouco ampla, mas não tem como me expressar melhor sobre isso, infelizmente.

Comment: Considero código dinâmico algo mutável sem reescrita de código. Ex.: Um código que suporte parametrização é dinâmico. Se nele empregar constantes, é estático. Mas vai de caso a caso.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Análise de código é uma coisa que parece diferente do que está sendo tratado. Existe a análise estática (uma ferramenta semelhante ao compilador faz isto no código fonte) e a análise dinâmica que rastreia a execução real do código.

Código estático, em determinado contexto, é um termo que tem pouca utilidade. Ele indica que o código foi gerado manual ou automaticamente (em *scaffolding*, por exemplo) em tempo de desenvolvimento.

Código dinâmico é aquele que é gerado em tempo de execução. Isto exige que a linguagem e o ambiente onde ele roda permitam que isto ocorra. Tem várias técnicas de realizar isto. Alguns mais seguros, outros perigosos. Eventualmente podemos dizer que a simples injeção de código pode ser uma dinamismo. Mas não sei se pode ser aplicado aqui se o código foi gerado anteriormente.

Talvez esteja falando de [*self modifying code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code).

Em outros contextos, pode significar outra coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: **self modifying code** é um "termo" que desconhecia. Achei interessante a explicação. +1